# Problem extending data series in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I've got a dual-axis chart with two series, is there something special needed to extend it with additional data?

When I try to extend it, the new xAsis label is added but the yAxis data points are not.

```
function addData(chart, label, data) {
    chart.data.labels.push(label);
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
            dataset.data.push(data);
    });
    chart.update();
}

var yArr = [64, 1.01];

addData(myChart, 'Sat', yArr);
```

[Here's my JSFiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/SmokeyRider/1fpah7or/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should push your new data into chartData object as per the yAxisID. try the following code.

```
 function addData(chart,label, data) {
    chart.data.labels.push(label);        

    for(var i=0; i< data.length; i++){
       for(var k=0; k< chartData.datasets.length; k++){
          if(chartData.datasets[k].yAxisID == data[i].yAxisID){
              chartData.datasets[k].data.push(data[i].value);
            }
          }
        }   
       chart.update();
       console.log(chart.data);
     }

  var yArr = [ {yAxisID:"F", value: 64},{yAxisID:"G", value: 1.01} ];
  addData(myChart,'Sat', yArr);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5botxckf/

Comment: Great, that works.  Thanks.  However, nested for statements seems somewhat inelegant.  Could there be a more minimalistic way where we just push an ordered pair of values?

Comment: @OdinAnderson I agree, it looks inelegant. This is a slight improvement.  function addData(chart,label, data) {
    chart.data.labels.push(label);    
    data.forEach(function(dataObj){
       var fieldId = chartData.datasets.find(obj => {
         return obj.yAxisID === dataObj.yAxisID 
       });
       fieldId.data.push(dataObj.value);           
       chart.update();                  
    });
 }      // Please check this js fillde.  https://jsfiddle.net/fjse1hpr/1/

Comment: yes, that's improved.  I updated the first function to an arrow function as well.
` function addData(chart,label, data) {
    chart.data.labels.push(label);    
    data.forEach(dataObj => {
       var fieldId = chartData.datasets.find(obj => {
         return obj.yAxisID === dataObj.yAxisID 
       });
       fieldId.data.push(dataObj.value);           
       chart.update();                  
    });
 }`